# Disable Media Controls in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am loading video from URL in WebView and I am using my own media controller so, I want to disable it's default media controls, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use VideoView instead of webview to customize the player controls.

Comment: I can not use videoview as i have to show videos from youtube also